# implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0' cause crash of application

Tags: admob

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'
where I add this line to gradle to monetise my application ,the application crash after starting.
thank for all to help me.

Comment: Could you please provide more information? Like what crash is this library causing? Stacktrace?

Comment: Probably you didn't add the application Id

Comment: Lukas:
thank you Lucas,
there are two times:
Firstly before adding this line (dependencies) the application start and work very normaly.
Secondly after adding this line, the application start and crash after a fiew milliseconds.

Comment: Unes: 
thank you Unes,
in the  manifest file:
<!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
        </activity>

Answer (score 0):

thank for all,
I found a solution,
it's work nicely,
but I m not sure that is the best solution and I don't know if this make some other problem.
I changed the built file content from:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

to:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).